# Error in Phone Gap Installation on windows 7

Tags: android, cordova, installation

I am newbie on Phonegap,  I am installing phonegap on my laptop which is having Windows 7 os installed I want to install it for android.

I have installed JRE 7 also jdk1.7.0_25  and Ant also.

I done with changes in Windows Script Host also (WSH).

Also I had set the all environment variables also.

I am following this [link](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-install-phonegap-for-android.html) but when I try to create a new project it is giving me

```
'cscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please help me. and if you need any screen shot or anything pleas ask me i can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out my blogpost "[A guide to PhoneGap on Windows](http://teusink.blogspot.nl/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html)" about this.

The tools below are at least required for PhoneGap 2.9.0.

- Android SDK tools
- Java JDK 6 or 7
- Integrated Development Environment (IDE): Eclipse and Eclipse Plugin OR Android Studio (still Beta!)
- Cordova PhoneGap

The tools below are at least required for PhoneGap 3.0.0.

- Android SDK tools
- Java JDK 6 or 7
- Integrated Development Environment (IDE): Eclipse and Eclipse Plugin OR Android Studio (still Beta!)
- Apache Ant
- GitHub
- Node.js
- Cordova PhoneGap

Hope it will work out for you.